# Cakephp empty $this->data after $.post submit through jquery

Tags: cakephp, jquery, jquery-post

I want to pass data to my ajax function in the controller, however the `$this->data` is empty.

I have in the JS:

```
$.post('/teach/update_word', {one: '1', two: '2'}, function (data){
    alert(data);
});
```

And in the Controller:

```
function update_word(){ // AJAX
    $output;
    if($this->data){
        $output['data']= 'yes';
    }else{
        $output['data']= 'no';
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
    die();
}
```

My function always returns `{"data":"no"}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only data that comes from (or looks like it is coming from) forms created by CakePHP's `FormHelper` end up in `$this->data`, so you would need to use fields names like `data[Word][one]`.

For all other data you would usually find in `$_POST`, you need to look in `$this->params['form'];` (or `$this->params['url']` for `$_GET`).

Comment: Jesus, been on this crap for hours. Should have written earlier... thanx a million!